# Why can't my C# find any lists on SharePoint?

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to create a folder on an Online SharePoint with the site url https://example.sharepoint.com/MySite

I really don't care anything about SharePoint lists, but I can't find any information towards a SharePoint API which hides this implementation detail from the consumer, nor any documentation which anticipates my needs well enough to tell me what I need to do, so I am struggling to work with the Lists.

At present, I just want to simply list whatever lists exist on my site.  My site has some minimalistic content, so I expect in a world were everything has lists, there should be some lists involved and I should be able to somehow list them.

I have the following code:

```
            using (ClientContext context = _authenticationManager.GetContext())
            {
                Web web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.Id));
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (List list in web.Lists)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(list.Title);
                }
            }
```

I've been able to use the debugger and the console to confirm the AuthenticationManager is successfully generating an authentication token.

When the code executes, `context.ExecuteQuery();` results in the following error:

> [14:49:48 INF] Successfully requested new access token resource example.sharepoint.com for user someuser@somemail.foo <s:SharepointOrderContractExtractor.Clients.AuthenticationManager>
> [14:49:48 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware>
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
> at SharePointOrderContractExtractor.Clients.Client.CreateFolder(String folderName) in C:\projects\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\Clients\Sharepoint\Client.cs:line 34
> at SharePointOrderContractExtractor.Services.SharePointService.CreateDestination(List`1 orderNumbers) in C:\projects\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\Services\SharepointService.cs:line 128 at SharePointOrderContractExtractor.Services.SharePointService.CollectForAsync(List`1 orderNumbers) in C:\projects\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\Services\SharepointService.cs:line 95
> at SharePointOrderContractExtractor.Services.SharePointService.FetchContractsAsync(FileUploadModel uploadModel) in C:\projects\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\Services\SharepointService.cs:line 51
> at SharePointOrderContractExtractor.Controllers.V1_0.SharePointController.Upload(FileUploadModel uploadModel) in C:\projects\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\SharepointOrderContractExtractor\Controllers\V1_0\SharepointController.cs:line 48
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?
How can I correct this?

Comment: `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.` Does the website exist at the url you're using?

Comment: Wouldn't that be prerequisite to authenticating on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @arconaut for his question in the comments:

It seems the Authentication Manager only uses the domain, not the full URL in order to authenticate.

While my site URL was set to https://example.sharepoint.com/MySite, it should have been https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite.

(I think I dropped "sites" from the configuration while trying to follow some documentation which may not have matched my version of Salesforce.)